# Book about people with special powers, recruited to fighting a war against others with powers

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a book about people with special abilities a while back (early-mid 2000's) in which there was a girl and her brother.  There were certain people in the book who had abilities and had to go fight a war against other people with abilities.

I think the girl's power was talking to animals (bugs etc...)  and her brother I think had the power of persuasion in that he would always seem to get people to do things for him...  something along those lines?

I also remember there was a group of men from the kingdom who tracked down people with special powers, one of them having the ability to find said people as his power...

Comment: Hi there! That's some really useful info in there already, but just in case,please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories that you could [edit] in - for instance, any recollection of what the cover looked like? Stuff like that, however minor it may seem, can help others remember/search the book. Cheers :)

Comment: You mention kingdoms. Was this a medieval fantasy? Kingdoms set in the present day? Did people do superhero tropes or was it more "ordinary people who have a special power but you wouldn't know it"?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! :)  Sorry, i tried quite a few search terms and couldn't seem to come up with anything

Comment: No worries, sometimes all it takes is a browser filled with enough "fantasy" cookies so that the right answer pops quite high in the Google results ;D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The Secret of Dragonhome* (1998) by John Peel?

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/764640.The_Secret_of_Dragonhome):

> Melayne and her young brother Sarrow are Talents, hunted by the King's relentless Seekers. If their Talent is discovered, they will be sent to their death. So they must hide...or die.
>
> Melayne and Sarrow find refuge at Dragonhome, the mysterious estate of the shadowy Lord Sander. Lord Sander also has something to hide--a dark and fantastical secret that haunts his every move. In order to save herself and her brother, Melayne must confront forces much stronger than her talent--tempests of magic, desire, and betrayal. If Melayne is not careful, her truth will be revealed.
>
> Melayne must unlock the secrets of Dragonhome. As danger approaches, it will be her only hope.

[This review](http://www.angelfire.com/dragon/dragonhome/review.html) mentions Melayne talking to animals and the brother having a Persuasion talent:

> Melayne has the "Talent" of communication, which allows her to speak with anything that is alive (this does not include trees). Sarrow, Melayne's younger brother, has the Talent of Persuasion, you don't find this out till very late near the end of the book. Sarrow's Talent allows him to persuade any human or Talent very easily into doing what he wants, this works better on "normals" (normal human beings without Talents) better than it works on Talents.

The same review also mentions the Seekers, Talents with the ability to find other Talents and send them to war:

> They are seen by a Seeker (a Talent who can detect other Talents by the way their brains are) and are braught to the King's House, a place where they prepare Talents for a war completely made to kill all Talents.

---

Found with the Google query `book talk to animals persuasion war brother sister` which returned the Goodreads page.

Comment: that's it, thanks so much!

Comment: @user958209 you're welcome, enjoy the re-read!